# Consolidate data from several sheets between two "bookends" into one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to tweak some code I already have that consolidates data from multiple sheets into a single, master sheet.

Currently the VBA selects all sheets that starts with the prefix "A-", copies select cells and pastes them into the consolidation sheet.

The change I would like to make is rather than select sheets starting with "A-", instead select all sheets between two sheets. For Simplicity, let's call these "StartSheet" and "EndSheet"

Illustratively it would look something like this:

< startsheet >  < analysis1 >  < analysis2 >  < analysis3 >  < endsheet >

Reason being, I, or someone else, can then just drop the analysis sheets between the bookends without risk of lookups and naming conventions.

I've tried a few ways to attempt to fuse my existing code with other examples I have found online but none seem to work. Help greatly appreciated!!

```
Sub compile()

   SelectSheets "A-", ThisWorkbook

     'Some other bits and pieces here
    End Sub


    Sub SelectSheets(sht As String, Optional wbk As Workbook)

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim ArrWks() As String
    Dim I As Long

    If wbk Is Nothing Then Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook

    ReDim ArrWks(0 To Worksheets.Count - 1)
    For Each wks In Worksheets
        If InStr(1, wks.Name, sht) > 0 Then
            ArrWks(I) = wks.Name
            I = I + 1
        End If
    Next wks
    ReDim Preserve ArrWks(I - 1)
    Sheets(ArrWks).Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each ws In Sheets(ArrWks)
    ws.Range("A23:CU27,A35:CU54,A56:CU58,A62:CU71,A74:CU84").Copy
    Worksheets("consol").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)


Next ws


    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Gear off the `.Index` property of your bookend sheets

Comment: @chrisneilsen I'm not sure what you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer!

```
Sub COMPILE()
   Dim i As Long

   For i = Sheets("Start").Index + 1 To Sheets("End").Index - 1
      Sheets(i).Range("A23:CU27,A35:CU54,A56:CU58,A62:CU71,A74:CU84").Copy
      Worksheets("consol").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   Next i
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```